# VBA wildcard statement

Tags: excel, vba

VBA is having difficulty finding my files using the wildcard *.  Is there an issue with the syntax in this statement?

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx Charts\xxxx Source Files\*_history_" & myYear & "-" & myMonth & "-" & mydate & "_" & myHour & "h" & myminute & "m" & "00s_xxx_all_xxx.csv"
```

where the wildcard I'm trying to match is Capital Letter, number,number,number, hyphen, number, number, number, number like this:  A999-9999

Note: if I type out the A999-9999 (for example) it runs, so there does not appear to be an issue with the variables or the rest of the statement.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: @portlandrunner FileSearch was deprecated in Office 2007 - not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this pointed at your directory to find all `csv` files matching "*-*.csv" with a second stage check to open the first file matching your desired file pattern

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim WB As Workbook
    StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*-*.csv")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    If StrFile Like "[A-Z]###-####.csv" Then
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\" & StrFile)
    bFound = True
    Exit Do
    Else
        StrFile = Dir
    End If
    Loop
    If Not bFound Then MsgBox "File not found", vbCritical
End Sub
```